# Firebase is not picking up my index.js located in functions folder

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I want to make sure if Firebase automatically hosts whatever html file is in "Public" folder located in my root directory and if it can't find that, it will host whatever is sitting inside "functions" folder. Is it correct? Or does it specifically look for index.html within Public folder and then specifically look for index.js within functions folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation for [Firebase Hosting rewrites to Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions):

> Note: The static files in the public directory take precedence over
>   the rewrites, so any static files will be served alongside the Cloud
>   Functions endpoints.

So, static content always gets served in preference to rewrites to Cloud Functions.

A request for / that results in a lookup for index.html will always prefer the static content in index.html if it exists.

You should make sure your static content doesn't "shadow" any of your functions, based on a comparison of their exact paths.

Comment: yeah but it doesn't explain if it will "look for functions folder" if I delete all the static files in Public right? So where exactly would it look if I delete all the static files in Public?

Comment: Nothing in your Cloud Functions folder will get ever get served as static content.  Hosting just looks at your public folder (or whatever you named it in firebase.json) for static content.

Comment: I'm talking about an actual local folder within my Mac computer with the name "functions". Also I'm not really sure  what Cloud Functions is.

Comment: Then I have no idea what you're concerned about.  What do you think is going to go wrong here?

Comment: well like I said, I do know that Firebase will look for index.html within Public folder first and if there isn't any, it will look "somewhere else" but where is that "somewhere else"? is it functions folder? is it some other folder? where is it?

Comment: Where are you getting the idea that there is somewhere else?  Please cite the documentation.

Comment: so are you saying that if Firebase can't find index.html in Public then it won't look anywhere?? if that's the case, I'm not sure why the Firebase tutorial guy said delete index.html if I wanted to host a dynamic web app with node.js.

Comment: Right, that's when you're involving Cloud Functions, which I talked about earlier.  I think you might need to review the documentation on both of these products and how they connect.

Comment: I see. so just to check if I got this correct, IF there's index.html file sitting in Public folder, Firebase will just host that but IF there isn't index.html file sitting in Public folder, then firebase won't look anywhere but just run Cloud Functions instead right away right?

Comment: If static content isn't found, if will send to Cloud Functions if you have a rewrite rule configured correctly to do that.

Comment: "If static content isn't found" -> does that mean if there ins't any .html files in Public folder? what if there's static content outside of Public? what would happen in that case?

Comment: We're going around this too many times.  I think it would be helpful if you actually worked with the products to get a sense of how they work.

Comment: it was an extremely simple question from the get go and it seems like you're not sure if Firebase looks only inside the Public folder or outside Public folder regarding index.html so you couldn't really answer that question. I even specifically asked about "sitting inside Public folder" and for some reason, you decided to dodge that part of the question and just make an extremely vague statement such as "If static content isn't found".

Comment: As I said, it doesn't ever look outside the configured public folder for static content.  Rewrites will be checked if static content for the requested URI isn't found.  If you have a very specific condition in mind that's not clear from the documentation, maybe you would like to ask a new question about that very specific condition?